# Command Binding in xaml with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Currently I'm trying to create my first Windows Application using C#, WPF, MVVM, see picture below.

[image: MainWindow]

My File structure:

[image: File Structure]

The goal of the application is to have a navigation menu on the left hand side, which can be used to navigate to different Content which has to be displayed in the white area (see picture above).

The "MenuItems" (6 buttons on the left hand side) in the navigation menu are used to change the content show in the white area. I create these buttons using the following code:

in my MainWindow.xaml I use an "ItemsControl" binding the "ItemScource" to a list of MenuItems.

MainWindows.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TSD.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TSD"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:TSD.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TSD.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TS Dashboard" Height="600" Width="1025" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="CanResize"
    WindowState="Normal"
    >

<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>

<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome 
    CaptionHeight="0"
    ResizeBorderThickness="5"/>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#2b6ea4" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
        <TextBlock x:Name="mainwindow_title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding MainWindowText}">
        </TextBlock>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75">
            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="25" Name="min_button" Click="MinimizeButton_Click">
                <Image Source="/assets/mini.png" Height="10" Width="10"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="25" Name="max_button" Click="MaximizeButton_Click">
                <Image Source="/assets/max.png" Height="10" Width="10"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="25" Name="close_button" Click="CloseButton_Click">
                <Image Source="/assets/close.png" Height="10" Width="10"/>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2">
        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>

        <ItemsControl Background="#2B6EA4" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="NavigationMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Width="auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            
        </ItemsControl>
        
    </Grid>
    
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HcfContentViewModel}">
                    <views:UserControlHcfContent/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:SLDContentViewModel}">
                    <views:UserControlSLDContent/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
    
</Grid>
```

I use my code behind to set the MainWindowViewModel as DataContext.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        NavigationStore navigationStore = new NavigationStore();
        MainWindowViewModel MWVM = new MainWindowViewModel(navigationStore);
        //MWVM.CurrentViewModel = new SLDContentViewModel();
        //MWVM.CurrentViewModel = new HcfContentViewModel();

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = MWVM;
    }


    //Window control buttons title bar
    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //Close button function
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void MinimizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //Minimize button
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void MaximizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //Maximize button
    {
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
    }

    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    //draggable window
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            this.DragMove();
    }


} //Class
```

In my MainWindowViewModel I create a list of UserControls, each UserControl representing a button in the navigation menu, this list is called _menuItems and is binded to the ItemsControl show earlier.

MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainWindowViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
    {
        //Set name for window.
        _MainWindowText = "My first MVVM application";
        _ImagePath = "/assets/placeholder_image_name.png";

        //Create MenuItems
        UserControlMenuItem Item1 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "ISSUE LIST", "/assets/issue_list_icon.png");
        UserControlMenuItem Item2 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "SYSTEM SHORTLOG DOWNLOAD","/assets/sld_icon.jpg");
        UserControlMenuItem Item3 = new UserControlMenuItem(navigateHcfCommand, "HOSE CONNECTION FINDER", "/assets/hose_icon.png");
        UserControlMenuItem Item4 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "GET CONFIG", "/assets/config_icon.png");
        UserControlMenuItem Item5 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "KNOWLEDGE TRANSFER", "/assets/knowledge_transfer_icon.png");
        UserControlMenuItem Item6 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "AMBITION LISTS", "/assets/ambition_list_icon.png");
        
        //Properties
        _MenuItems = new List<UserControlMenuItem> { Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6 };
        _navigationStore = navigationStore;

        //Commands used in this view
        dummyCommand = new DummyCommand();
        navigateHcfCommand = new ShowHcfCommand(_navigationStore);
    }

    // Class fields
    private string _MainWindowText;
    private List<UserControlMenuItem> _MenuItems;
    private string _ImagePath;
    private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;
    // Commands
    public ICommand navigateHcfCommand;
    public ICommand dummyCommand;


    //Class properties
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get => _ImagePath;
        set {
            _ImagePath = ImagePath;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
        }
    }

    public string MainWindowText
    {
        get => _MainWindowText;
        set {
            _MainWindowText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainWindowText");
        }
    }

    public List<UserControlMenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get => _MenuItems;
        set {
            _MenuItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MenuItems");
        }
    }

    public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get => _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel;
        set { _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = value; }
    }

    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    //
    // Events
    //

    //Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}// Class
```

UserControlMenuItem ( To define layout of the buttons ) this UserControl is added to the list _menuItems in MainWindowViewModel:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TSD.Views.UserControlMenuItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TSD.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
    <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding Command}">

        <Grid>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0"  Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <Image Source="{Binding MenuItem.ItemImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30" Height="30"></Image>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Content="{Binding MenuItem.ItemName}" Width="200" Height="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
               Foreground="black"
               Margin="0,2,2,0">

                </Label>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>

    </Button>

</Border>
```

The UserControlMenuItem has a MenuItemViewModel.cs containing th following code:

```
class MenuItemViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public MenuItemViewModel(string ItemName, string ItemImage, ICommand Command)
    {
        _MenuItem = new MenuItemModel(ItemName, ItemImage);
        _command = Command;
    }

    private MenuItemModel _MenuItem;
    public ICommand _command;

    public MenuItemModel MenuItem
    {
        get { return _MenuItem; }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
    }


} // Class
```

and the MenuItemModel.cs :

```
class MenuItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _ItemName;
    private string _ItemImage;

    public MenuItemModel(string itemname, string itemimage)
    {
        _ItemName = itemname;
        _ItemImage = itemimage;
    }

    public string ItemName
    {
        get => _ItemName;
        set {
            _ItemName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemName");
        }
    }

    public string ItemImage
    {
        get => _ItemImage;
        set {
            _ItemImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemImage");
        }
    }

    //
    // Events
    //

    //Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the first picture this is working fine, the issue is within binding the command to change the "content area" (White area first picture).

I'll shortly try to describe the code for the content area here:
In MainWindow.xaml (first code snippet) you'll see a "ContentControl", here I bind the CurrentViewModel, which represent content to be displayed in the content area. I use a navigationStore to store the ViewModel which has to be displayed.

navigationStore.cs:

```
public class NavigationStore
{
    public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

and an example of a "content page":
View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TSD.Views.UserControlHcfContent"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TSD.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Search:"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="150"></TextBox>
        <Button Margin="50,0,0,0" Padding="10,0,10,0" Content="Create new system"></Button>
        <Button Margin="50,0,0,0" Padding="10,0,10,0" Content="Edit existing system"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
    
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    
    </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
class HcfContentViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public HcfContentViewModel()
    {
        //Check here for available systems and create model accordingly.
        _hcfContent = new HcfContentModel();
    }

    private HcfContentModel _hcfContent;

    public HcfContentModel hcfContent
    {
        get { return _hcfContent; }
    }

}
```

Model:

```
class HcfContentModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _activeProductName;
    private int _availableProducts;
    
    public HcfContentModel()
    {

    }

    public string activeProductName
    {
        get => _activeProductName;
        set 
        {
            _activeProductName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("activeProductName");
        }
    }

    public int availableProducts
    {
        get => _availableProducts;
        set 
        {
            _availableProducts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("availableProducts");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Problem statement:

When pressing/Clicking an ItemMenu in the navigation menu the command is not triggerd.
I'm trying to execute the ShowHcfCommand to change the content area to the HcfViewModel.

ShowHcfCommand:

```
class ShowHcfCommand : BaseCommand
{
    private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;

    public ShowHcfCommand(NavigationStore navigationStore)
    {
        _navigationStore = navigationStore;
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = new HcfContentViewModel();
        Console.WriteLine("Command Executed!");
    }
}
```

I hope the information provided is sufficient and clear, if not please let know so I can update it.
The complete project can be cloned from my github page:

https://github.com/SaCam/FirstApp

I'm using VS2017.

If there are tips on how to improve the general project layout please let me know.

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards,
Sam

Comment: From where exactly are you trying to execute the command?

Answer (score 1):

in MainWindowViewModel.cs you never instantiate an instance of your command

```
public ICommand navigateHcfCommand; //not instantiated
```

but used in the Constructor:

```
       UserControlMenuItem Item3 = new UserControlMenuItem(navigateHcfCommand, "HOSE CONNECTION FINDER", "/assets/hose_icon.png");
```

The Menu Item is bound to a null command.
If you change that it'll still not show the correct contentviewmodel because you don't call property changed or any other event from the navigationstore class

Comment: Yes, this solved the command not being executed. I fixed it and it now is executed, but, like you already mentioned it does not change the view. I added a OnPropertyChanged in my MainWindowViewModel but still it won't change, any tips or idea on where exactly I should call this ?

Comment: You really should implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the BaseViewModel so you don't have to duplicate it everywhere. But anyway quickest fix: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on NavigationStore.cs, then in the constructor of MainWindowViewModel subscribe to the event and call the OnPropertyChanged of MainWindowViewModel.CurrentViewModel.You subscribe to events like this: _navigationStore.PropertyChanged += _navigationStore_PropertyChanged;  Then a method   private void _navigationStore_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentViewModel));}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Thanks for the help.

After following the comment op T.Schwarz I managed to get it working.

I updated my MainWindowViewModel.cs to fix the null command I was assigning.
This initially fixed the issue of the command not being executed, but as mentiond by T.Schwarz it would still not change the view. I had to notify Property Changed within my MainWindowViewModel and not from the navigationStore. the updated MainWindowViewModel is shown below.:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // Class fields
    private string _MainWindowText;
    private List<UserControlMenuItem> _MenuItems;
    private string _ImagePath;
    private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;

    // Commands
    public ICommand navigateHcfCommand;
    public ICommand dummyCommand;


    public MainWindowViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
    {
        //Stores
        _navigationStore = navigationStore;

        //Commands used in this view
        dummyCommand = new DummyCommand();
        navigateHcfCommand = new ShowHcfCommand(this);

        //Set name for window.
        _MainWindowText = "My first MVVM application";
        _ImagePath = "/assets/placeholder_image_name.png";

        //Create MenuItems
        UserControlMenuItem Item1 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "ISSUE LIST", "/assets/issue_list_icon.png");
        UserControlMenuItem Item2 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "SYSTEM SHORTLOG DOWNLOAD","/assets/sld_icon.jpg");
        UserControlMenuItem Item3 = new UserControlMenuItem(navigateHcfCommand, "HOSE CONNECTION FINDER", "/assets/hose_icon.png");
        UserControlMenuItem Item4 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "GET CONFIG", "/assets/config_icon.png");
        UserControlMenuItem Item5 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "KNOWLEDGE TRANSFER", "/assets/knowledge_transfer_icon.png");
        UserControlMenuItem Item6 = new UserControlMenuItem(dummyCommand, "AMBITION LISTS", "/assets/ambition_list_icon.png");
        
        //Properties
        _MenuItems = new List<UserControlMenuItem> { Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6 };
    }


    //Class properties
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get => _ImagePath;
        set {
            _ImagePath = ImagePath;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
        }
    }

    public string MainWindowText
    {
        get => _MainWindowText;
        set {
            _MainWindowText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainWindowText");
        }
    }

    public List<UserControlMenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get => _MenuItems;
        set {
            _MenuItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MenuItems");
        }
    }

    public BaseViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get => _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel;
        set {
            _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }

    public ICommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    //
    // Events
    //

    //Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}// Class
```

As you can see from the code above, I now pass my MainWindowViewModel to the ShowHcfCommand, within this command I change the value of CurrentViewModel in the MainWindowViewModel.

It is working now, however I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution or if it is inline with "general" MVVM rules. If anyone has tips on how to improve the structure please let me know.

Kind regards,
Sam